# How to find all <button> with type=submit without any name nor value attributes?

Tags: jquery

I currently use this to disable all `<button>` once the form is submitted / button clicked:

```
$('.my-form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

But this also disables all `<button>` with meaningful name and value such as:

```
<button type="submit" name="confirm" value="1" />
<button type="submit" name="confirm" value="0" />
```

Those useful values are NOT submitted because the button is disabled.

How can I select all `<button>` with type=submit but without any name nor value attributes? I tried to google but only found something like `[attribute!='value']` which I was not able to combine into what I already have.

Comment: Can't u give a class to all the buttons u wanna disable?

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a *named* or a *valued* `button`?

Comment: @Shivam, it's a chore and error-prone to manually find and update all the buttons in a large code base you maintain over time. It's not the programmer way.

Comment: @PeterKA, Sometimes it's really intuitive to have multiple buttons in a form than with a single 'Submit' but forces user to click around some radios and checkboxes.

Comment: True that kavir.com!!!

Comment: Is `<button type="submit" name="confirm" value="1" />` valid `html` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attributes itself is not present then

```
$('.my-form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]:not([name]):not([value])').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.filter()`

```js
$("button").filter(function(i, el) {
  return !el.value && !el.name
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" name="confirm" value="1">1</button>
<button type="submit" name="confirm" value="0">0</button>
<button type="submit">abc</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple attribute selectors like this:

`button[type="submit"][name!="confirm"]`

Although note that the `!=` is part of jQuery, and not a native selector.  You should use the `.not()` syntax for better performance in modern browsers: `$( "your-pure-css-selector" ).not( "[name='value']" )`

[Info on jQuery Site](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)